# Read Data from Temperature Controller using MATLAB, Need Help

Tags: sensor, temperature, pid-controller, matlab, rs485

I am trying to read data from a temperature controller called [ATR-401](https://www.ucontrol.com.au/manuals/atr401_it_eng.pdf) using MATLAB's tool box called **Instrument Control Toolbox** but every time i try to read data from it i get an error "A timeout occurred before the Terminator was reached". I have attached 2 images below ,First one is the configurations i used to connect to the device and the second image is the reading data from the device :

[image: Configure ATR-401]

[image: Reading from Controller]

As it can be seen, i get an error while reading, i have set it according to the datasheet for the device but i am still not sure why it is not able to read.

Comment: There is nothing in your post about baud rate, stop bits, parity bits, ect. If you don't set those correctly then you won't be able to communicate to the temp controller *with any serial program*

Comment: I have already set the  Baud Rate: 19200 bps , 8 bits, none for parity and 1 for stop. in the first image. The device settings in the datasheet are shown on Pg 27 of the link in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step 1) Get a serial terminal program  (like realterm)
Step 2) Set the device to your RS485 controller
Step 3) Set the baud rate (the default for the temp controller is 19200 baud)
Step 4) Set the stop bits and parity bits 8, N, 1 (8 bit, no parity, 1 stop)
Step 5)

> EN26Parameter   has  the  same  meaning  of  cycle  time  for  heating
>   action .Parameter   (Cooling  Fluid)  pre-selects  the  proportional 
>   band  multiplier  and the cooling P.I.D. cycle time  according to
>   cooling fluid type:Cooling fluid type Air1.00 10Oil 1.254Water2.502 Once
>   parameter , has been selected, the parameters , and  can be however
>   modified.9  Serial CommunicationATR401-22ABC-T is provided with RS485
>   and can receive / broadcast data  via  MODBUS-RTU  protocol.  Device 
>   can  be  configured  only  as Slave.This  function  allows  to 
>   control  multiple  controllers  connected  to  a  supervisory system. 
>   Each instrument will answer to a Master query only if contains same
>   address as on parameter 93 .Allowed addresses are from 1 to 254 and
>   there should not be controllers with the same address on the same
>   line.Address  255  can  be  used  by  the  Master  to  communicate 
>   with  all  connected  equipment's  (broadcast  mode),  while  with  0 
>   all  devices  receive command, but no answer is expected.ATR401  can 
>   introduce  an  answer  delay  (in  milliseconds)  to  Master 
>   request.This delay has to be set on parameter 94 .At each parameters
>   modification, instrument stores values in EEPROM memory (100000
>   writing cycles), while setpoints are stored with a delay of 10 seconds
>   after last modification.

Then see if you can access one of the registers and read values out of it.

Once you have done this in realterm, then transfer the baud rate/stop/parity bits to matlab and try and read the register there.

Comment: So i used Tera Term and reached step 4, but how do i access the registers and read  values out of it ?

Comment: The manual is not clear on that, and it's not clear on if there are any special characters either (like terminator characters). Check to see if there is more documentation from the manufacturer

Comment: That is the only documentation from the manufacturer , so how do i  access the registers from Tera Term ? because i did until step 4) as described above.

Comment: Try this: https://www.yoctopuce.com/EN/article/a-quick-tutorial-on-rs485-and-modbus